# How to create an icon for Homebrew installed software (Evince) in macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, pdf

I installed Evince, the PDF reader that comes pre-installed with several major GNU/Linux distributions, on Mac OS X using:

```
 brew install evince
```

Now, to open it, I have to type every single time "evince" on terminal.

Is there any way to create an icon for that program, that could be moved in my applications folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use a wrapper like Platypus.

- Download and install the script wrapper [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus).
- Create a shell script `/usr/local/bin/evince.sh` with the content:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  /usr/local/bin/evince
  ```
- Open Platypus and create a new app like indicated in the screenshot below:

  [image]
- Choose a nice [icon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Evince_logo.svg/1024px-Evince_logo.svg.png) (1024 x 1024 px linked) like this one:

  [image] (48 x 48 px example)

  And hit the create button.
- Save the app to an appropriate folder (e.g. `/Applications`) and create a Dock item.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking apps with this command:

```
brew linkapps evince
```

If there are .app-style macOS wrapper apps in its formula, it will be linked to `/Applications`. You can alternatively link those apps to `~/Applications` with this command:

```
brew linkapps --local evince
```

You can check if linking is successful with:

```
ls -lrth /Applications
```

Now look at the last lines if there are "evince" related items in the list.

If linking was not successful, try to link it manually. You can link "evince" executable file to `/Applications`:

```
ln -s $(which evince) /Applications/Evince
```

Comment: this answer doesn't work in 2023 on macOS ventura. I get `Error: Unknown command: linkapps`