# Create Dock Icon for Spyder (installed with Anaconda)

Tags: dock, icon, python

How can I create a single dock icon for an application that is launched via the Terminal?

I have installed spyder using anaconda. I can create a launcher app using Platypus (see this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256987/creating-an-icon-for-a-homebrew-installed-software-evince-mac-os-x)). But the actual spyder-application opens a new (ugly) dock icon labeled "python" next to it:
[image: dock icons]

The confusion starts when I want to switch to the Spyder app: I have to click on the python icon and not on the spyder one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Platypus is not necessarily needed to add an icon to spyder:

Starting spyder in the CLI is a two stage process:

~/anaconda/bin/spyder is a shell script executing the "proxy app" ~/anaconda/bin/python.app which itself launches another "proxy app" ~/anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python including an argument.

---

Since the last shell script resides in an app bundle you can simply add an icon:

The two proxy apps are "wrappers/launchers" for all other python science apps included in Anaconda. You don't want to break Anaconda - therefore you have to create two "spyder-only" launchers.

Make a copy of ~/anaconda/bin/python.app: ~/anaconda/bin/python.spyder.app and change the shell script inside (don't forget to also change the user in the path!).

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONEXECUTABLE=/Users/user/anaconda/bin/python
/Users/user/anaconda/python.spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

Then create a copy of ~/anaconda/python.app: ~/anaconda/python.spyder.app and add an icon to it.

Started from the Terminal the command `spyder` will launch python.spyder.app with the custom icon.

Now you may use Platypus to create an app to launch `spyder` (instead of using Terminal.app). Use the following settings:

[image: Platypus spyder]

This may break after an Anaconda or a spyder update.

---

I don't think you can run spyder with a single spyder dock icon (with the Platypus spyder launcher as a permanent Dock item) because the python.spyder.app/python.app itself is a wrapper for spyder again. So after hitting the Platypus spyder app icon in the Dock you will always get a second spyder icon - the reason why your solution shows the default python.app icon.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more of a programming question than a usability question, however it would probably have to be done programmatically as macOS normally looks for the icon inside the Application as part of a .plist file, and your application doesn't have this presumably because it's being run from command line as a script.

Have a look at: [Changing Cocoa app icon, title and menu labels at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808226/changing-cocoa-app-icon-title-and-menu-labels-at-runtime)